# setValues in the Google Apps script is very slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple script that copies value from one sheet and pastes into another, however it takes 10+ mins every single time.

There are about 100K rows in the file. i have tried even separating them out but makes no difference.

```
function makeDataCopies()
{
  Logger.log("starts");
  var copyTo = DEST.getSheetByName(WSHEET);
  var copyFrom = SOURCE.getSheetByName(WSHEET);
  
  var copyArray = copyFrom.getDataRange().getValues();
 
  Logger.log("calls copy");
  copyTo.getRange(1,1,copyArray.length,copyArray[0].length).setValues(copyArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

I thought that from your situation of `There are about 100K rows in the file.`, I would like to propose to use Sheets API for your situation. When Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced from Google Spreadsheet service of SpreadsheetApp. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When your script is modified using Sheets API, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```
function makeDataCopies() {
  var dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID.
  var srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var WSHEET = "###"; // Please set the sheet name.

  var srcValues = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(srcSpreadsheetId, WSHEET).values;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: srcValues}, dstSpreadsheetId, WSHEET, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: @KES Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: now i am having issues with date fields. they are getting all messed up. i have tried both RAW and USER_ENTERED, each have their own issues. how could i overcome that?

Comment: @KES Thank you for replying. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `now i am having issues with date fields. they are getting all messed up. i have tried both RAW and USER_ENTERED, each have their own issues.`, I cannot understand about your situation. So, in order to correctly understand about it, by including more information, can you post it as new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?